# Mezzanine Blog: How do I only show blog post keywords instead of all keywords?

Tags: pycharm, blogs, mezzanine

So I have a Mezzanine blog running. (BTW, I'm a total newbie at Mezzanine). I've added some keywords on each individual post with the Admin tool.

For example, on one post called *Low Carb Diets Vs. Low Fat Diets*, I have keywords for this post listed as *Diet, Health, Wellness*.

They show correctly in the Admin tool in the keywords input text box for that post. However, when I try to only show those three keywords at the bottom of my post on the website, I instead get the entire blog's list of keywords:

*Allergies, Apps, Childrens Health, Diet, Exercise, Gluten-Free, Health, Healthy Lifestyle, Mental Health, Pollen, Sinus, Sleep, Technology, Wellness*

Here is my code for showing the keywords on each post's webpage (I'm using PyCharm by the way):

```
{% block blog_keywords %}
   {% keywords_for blog.blogpost as tags %}
   {% if tags %}
      {% for tag in tags %}
         <span class="postTag">
            <a href="{% url "blog_post_list_tag" tag.slug %}"
               class="tag-weight-{{ tag.weight }}">{{ tag }}</a>
         </span>
      {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a setting or code that I need to adjust to show only the post's individual tags on each post webpage?

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant section from the default blog_post_detail.html template, which is slightly different to your code:

```
{% block meta_keywords %}{% metablock %}
{% keywords_for blog_post as tags %}
{% for tag in tags %}{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %}
{% endmetablock %}{% endblock %}
```

File location inside my python 2.7 virtual env:

```
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/blog/templates/blog/blog_post_detail.html
```